# Instances Of Firefox Browser In Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I am building an extension in Firefox and I wonder if there is a way to know when opening a browser how many instances are open using javascript?

For example I open one instance of Firefox browser I want to get the number of the current instances.

Any ideas?

Comment: By instances are you talking about single tabs or windows (each with it's own set of tabs)?

Comment: That i'm not sure how you do it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that may help you:

[nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator#getEnumerator%28%29) is a component that keeps track of open windows. It has `getEnumerator` method that allows you to get all open windows.

If you loop through it, and count them, you get the number of open windows, like so:

```
var windowMediator = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);

var enumerator = windowMediator.getEnumerator(null);
var count = 0;
while (enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
    var myWindow = enumerator.getNext();
    count++;
}
alert(count);
```